# How to define a type omitting one shared prop from a union but including the rest of them along with union members' private props?

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces (`Foo` and `Bar`) that extend the same base interface. The two interfaces form together a union (`DiscriminatingUnion`), so objects of that type have the props of the base interface and the private props of each union member interface.

I want to create a new type that is the same as the aforementioned union with the exception that one of the base props is omitted. How to do this? Using `Omit<>` doesn't seem to work because it apparently turns into a `Pick<>` that ignores the private props of a union member.

**TL;DR:** I want `testObject.bar` to exist in case block "bar" and `testObject.foo` to exist in case block "foo" in the example below:

```js
interface Base { propToOmit: string; propToKeep: string }
interface Foo extends Base { type: "foo"; foo: string }
interface Bar extends Base { type: "bar"; bar: string }
type DiscriminatingUnion = Foo | Bar;
type OmitFromDiscUnion = Omit<DiscriminatingUnion, "propToOmit">;

const fooObject: DiscriminatingUnion = {
  type: "foo",
  foo: "",
  propToOmit: "",
  propToKeep: ""
};

const barObject: DiscriminatingUnion = {
  type: "bar",
  bar: "",
  propToOmit: "",
  propToKeep: ""
};

const testArray: OmitFromDiscUnion[] = [fooObject, barObject];
testArray.forEach((testObject) => {
  switch (testObject.type) {
    case "bar":
      // Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Pick<DiscriminatingUnion, "type" | "propToKeep">'.
      testObject.bar;        // Doesn't exist, but I want it to exist!
      testObject.foo;        // Doesn't exist as expected (switch-case).
      testObject.propToOmit; // Doesn't exist as expected (omitted).
      testObject.propToKeep; // Exists as expected.
      break;
    case "foo":
      // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Pick<DiscriminatingUnion, "type" | "propToKeep">'.
      testObject.foo;        // Doesn't exist, but I want it to exist!
      testObject.bar;        // Doesn't exist as expected (switch-case).
      testObject.propToOmit; // Doesn't exist as expected (omitted).
      testObject.propToKeep; // Exists as expected.
      break;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I can use `Extract<DiscriminatingUnion, { /* allowed props */ }>` to achieve this. I'm unsure whether this is the optimal solution.

Using `Extract<DiscriminatingUnion, {/*hard coded type*/}>` is bad because it's hard coded. A solution I'd appreciate would somehow achieve the goal by defining the new union using the union member types and somehow excluding one specific prop from there.

```js
interface Base { propToOmit: string; propToKeep: string }
interface Foo extends Base { type: "foo"; foo: string }
interface Bar extends Base { type: "bar"; bar: string }
type DiscriminatingUnion = Foo | Bar;
// NEW
type OmitFromDiscUnion = Extract<DiscriminatingUnion, {
  // Hard coded, bad! Optimal solution would use the defined types somehow!
  propToKeep: string;
  type: string;
  foo?: string;
  bar?: string;
}>;

const fooObject: DiscriminatingUnion = {
  type: "foo",
  foo: "",
  propToOmit: "",
  propToKeep: ""
};

const barObject: DiscriminatingUnion = {
  type: "bar",
  bar: "",
  propToOmit: "",
  propToKeep: ""
};

const testArray: OmitFromDiscUnion[] = [fooObject, barObject];
testArray.forEach((testObject) => {
  switch (testObject.type) {
    case "bar":
      // NEW
      testObject.bar;        // Exists now!
      testObject.foo;        // Doesn't exist as expected (switch-case).
      testObject.propToOmit; // Doesn't exist as expected (omitted).
      testObject.propToKeep; // Exists as expected.
      break;
    case "foo":
      // NEW
      testObject.foo;        // Exists now!
      testObject.bar;        // Doesn't exist as expected (switch-case).
      testObject.propToOmit; // Doesn't exist as expected (omitted).
      testObject.propToKeep; // Exists as expected.
      break;
  }
});
```